# Redirect for https and www

Tags: configuration, mod-rewrite, centos6, apache-2.4

I currently have my rewrite rules in the post_virtualhost_2.conf file
this in inserted into the httpd.conf file at the absolute end.

I have two blocks that don't seem to be working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The full conf is [here](https://gist.github.com/privatmamtora/83671f1416181fdfed22)

What I am expecting is the following in all cases

- https://www.privatmamtora.com

But when I enter privatmamtora.com it simply get a 200 response.

PS. I am hoping that the rules could be subdomain safe. (Not break subdomains)

**EDIT**

Rewrite module is loaded.

Comment: @GMambaG yes but with the httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which OS this is working with, so I'll keep it generic.

It's possible that the mod_rewrite module isn't enabled and so the config is ignored due to the `<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>`

You need to confirm that this module is actually loaded.

Also you don't need two sets of `<IfModule ...>`

This currently works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^WWW\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I can confirm that the rewrite_module is enabled (httpd -M).